# How to make a WCF Service to accept both JSON and XML requests?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How could make this WCF service endpoint to accept both JSON and XML requests?

As per client, the request to the WCF service endpoint may be either JSON or XML, but the operation to handle that request is the same.

void UpdateTask(string externalTicketId, string externalTaskId, string lastEditedByUser, string taskAction, string taskPrivateNote, string taskResult, string workTimeMinutes);

Comment: I think deserialization happens before your actual method call and controlled by attributes. You could solve your problem if you have different method names or different URLs, thus interface, altogether.